# Possibility to read .xtend on Geany text editor

Tags: text-editor, xtend, geany

**Context**: I would like to read file `.xtend`. Normally I use Geany as a text editor.

**Questions**:

1. Is it possible reading file `.xtend` on Geany? What I mean is that the language is recognized and the keywords highlighted.
2. If so, how to make it possible? Any procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xtend), Xtend is syntactically similar to Java. Try opening an Xtend file in Geany, setting the highlighting to Java by selecting `Document > Set Filetype > Programming Languages > Java source code`, and see if that serves the purpose. If it does, you can then create a custom filetype for `.xtend` files by copying the Java filetype and adding the appropriate configuration info [as noted in the Geany manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/index.html#custom-filetypes).

Comment: +1 I can see some color now! I don't know if the trick solves the problem: xtend is a kind of java simplification and maybe some keywords are different (I am not an expert: I am just starting)